# Cases and Entity

Tags: entity

When extracting the "name" of an `Entity` one has `CommonName`. Good. Before I discovered this, I simply applied a rule like:

```
en = Entity["Language", "English"];
en /. Entity[a_, b_] :> b (* out: "English"*)
```

Maybe I´m missing something stupid, but why does the following not work?

```
Cases[en, Entity[a_, b_] :> b] (* out: {} *)
```

Comment: `Cases[{en}, Entity[a_, b_] :> b]` works

Comment: Related: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CanonicalName.html

Comment: That is not restricted to `Entity` that is the usual behavior of `Cases`, for example, for an undefined variable `b`, `Cases[b,b]` outputs {}. The fix-> `Cases[en, Entity[a_, b_] :> b, All]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the *levelspec* as `{0}` using the third argument of `Cases`:

```
Cases[en, Entity[a_, b_] :> b, {0}]
(* or Cases[en, x_Entity:> Last[x], {0}] *)
```

> {"English"}

**Notes:** from [Cases >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html)

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

The last one explains why `Cases[{en}, Entity[a_, b_] :> b]` and, more generally, `Cases[foo[en], Entity[a_, b_] :> b]` gives `{"English"}`.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it must be something stupid simple....

Comment: @mgamer, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. It is easy to forget  the three argument form of `Cases`:)